# Failed to uniqueindex while updating subdocument in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Following is my db structure

```
{"dname" : "a",   "accounts" : [
        {
          'userId':'1',
          'name':'xyz'
         }
     ] 
 }
```

As i've added uniqueindex dname_1,dname_1_accounts.userId_1 to collection but when in update when i use push query as below

```
{$push:{"accounts" :{'userId':'1','name':'abc'}}}
```

or

```
{$addToSet:{"accounts" :{'userId':'1','name':'abc'}}}
```

It doesn't give error of unique key or any kind it adds duplicate key value to document

```
{"dname" : "a",   "accounts" : [
            {
              'userId':'1',
              'name':'xyz'
             },
             {
              'userId':'1',
              'name':'abc'
             }

         ] 
     }
```

how to avoid this issue using nativemongo querys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.coll.update({"dname" : "a","accounts.userId" :{$ne:'1'}},{$push:{"accounts" :{'userId':'1','name':'abc'}}})

this will not give error but it also avoid inserting duplicates with key **userId** in the accounts array

Comment: please suggest if there are any other solution for the problem

Answer (score 1):

Because your `userId` is stored inside of an `accounts`, your index would need to be on

```
accounts.userId
```

Run

```
db.coll.createIndex( { 'accounts.userId': 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

and your second insert statement should now fail.

Comment: i removed all documents but still i am unable to avoid duplicates

Comment: is there any way in mongonative to check uniqueindex during inserting same subdocument to avoid duplicates

Comment: Unfortunately not. You would need some app code that checks whether this ID is unique first.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't more helpful :)

Comment: you cleared my concept of index more clearly and i got the way with you guidance a solution that i've added as answer.